# How to get file path of shared storage folder in Android 10 and above?

Tags: android, scoped-storage, mp4parser

We are integrating scoped storage in our app, we are reading and writing video files in sahred storage e.g `Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES` folder (shared storage movies directory) it is working as expected but we need to write custom metadata in video to do that we are using `org.mp4parser:isoparser`. To read and write metadata, this library needs file object  before scoped storage we can get absolute path using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) now it's deprecated is there any other way to get the file path in scoped storage?

```
public static String readVideoMetadata(File videoFile) throws IOException {
    
        if (!videoFile.canRead()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No read permissions to file " + videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        if(!isImageFile(videoFile)) {
            try {
                IsoFile isoFile = new IsoFile(videoFile);
                if (null != Path.getPath(isoFile, "moov[0]/udta[0]/meta[0]/ilst/©cmt")) {
                    AppleCommentBox nam = Path.getPath(isoFile, "moov[0]/udta[0]/meta[0]/ilst/©cmt");
                    String xml = nam.getValue();
                    isoFile.close();
                    return xml;
                }
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError | Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            ExifInterface exifInterface=new ExifInterface(videoFile);
            String metaData= exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_USER_COMMENT);
            if(metaData!=null){
                return metaData;
            }
        }
    
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQkwcJG4YTCR9jZq8O19nUL2hLqmLYX4M this is a great video tutorial on youtube, have a look

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I implemented code to save, delete create files, need to write custom metadata in video using mp4parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use FFMPEG Android library](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/tree/development/android)

You can get file path from media URI using the below code

```
Uri safUri = intent.getData();
String inputVideoPath = FFmpegKitConfig.getSafParameterForRead(requireContext(), safUri);
```

You can read media information using this below function

```
 MediaInformationSession mediaInformation = FFprobeKit.getMediaInformation("<file path or uri>");
mediaInformation.getMediaInformation();
```